# Enviando mensagens Push Notification para mais de 1000 usuários de uma só vez

Tags: php, push-notification

Esta dúvida é muito frequente e já vi alguns posts no Stack em inglês que exemplificam (sem ser muito objetivas) como resolver o problema. O GCM limita o envio de uma mesma mensagem a 1000 dispositivos cadastrados em um banco de dados, de uma só vez. Caso haja mais de 1000 dispositivos a mensagem não é sequer enviada. Seria preciso um Loop que separasse os registros em lotes de 1000 registros e dar um salto a cada quantidade. Ex. se tiver 5000 seriam 5 repetições de 1000 para a mesma mensagem: Segue abaixo o código PHP que obtive (e é o mesmo em vários sites) e que me limita a esta quantidade, alguém teria alguma solução?

```
class GCM {

    function __construct(){}

    public function send_notification ($registatoin_ids, $data) {

        require "includes/google_api_key.php";

        // GOOGLE API KEY
        define ("GOOGLE_API_KEY", $google_api_key);

        $url = "https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send";

        $fields = array (
            "registration_ids" => $registatoin_ids,
            "data" => $data,
        );
        //var_dump($fields);
        $headers = array(
            "Authorization: key=".GOOGLE_API_KEY,
            "Content-Type: application/json"
        );
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
        $result_gcm=curl_exec($ch);
        if($result_gcm===FALSE) {
            die("Curl failed: ".curl_error($ch));
        }
        curl_close($ch);
        //echo $result_gcm;
    }
}



// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($mysqlHost, $mysqlUser, $mysqlPwd, $mysqlDbname);

// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die ("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}


$result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM tbl_notification WHERE users_android_token IS NOT NULL AND users_android_token <> ''");

$android_tokens = array();
$x = 0;

if ($result -> num_rows > 0) {       // Acredito que aqui seria  
                                     // o local para inserir um laço for
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result -> fetch_assoc()) {
         $android_tokens[] = $row["users_android_token"];
    $x++;
    }
} else {
    echo "";
}
$conn -> close();

$title  = $_POST['title'];
$msg    = $_POST['message'];
$link   = $_POST['link'];

if ($android_tokens != array()) {
    $gcm  = new GCM();
    $data = array("title" => $title,"description" => $msg,"link" => $link);
    $result_android = $gcm -> send_notification($android_tokens,$data);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar o [`array_chunk`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-chunk.php) para dividir em pedaços de 1000 e depois enviar.

```
if ($android_tokens != array()) {
    $gcm  = new GCM();
    $data = array("title" => $title,"description" => $msg,"link" => $link);

    //Dividi o array contendo 1000 tokens
    $splitTokens = array_chunk($android_tokens, 1000);

    //Da um looping no array dividido e envia em lotes de 1000
    //Obs: o último lote pode conter menos
    foreach($splitTokens as $tokens) {
        $result_android = $gcm -> send_notification($tokens,$data);
    }

}
```

Comment: Excelente. Eu já havia visto esta sugestão no Stack em Inglês, porém não tão objetivamente. Inserir isto em meu script e agora devo deixar chegar  a 1.000 usuários novamente. Havia deletado alguns registros para continuar a enviar. Assim que tiver um retorno positivo marco como certo.

Comment: Jeferson Assis, perfeito sua solução. Hoje o BD está com mais de 1.005 e o sistema continuar funcionando.

Answer (score 1):

Encontrei uma outra solução que faz a mesma coisa que o código enviado anteriormente, apenas para que quem tenha problemas com uma maneira, poderá tentar a outra:

Inserir após :

```
$result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_android_token IS NOT NULL AND user_android_token <> '' ORDER BY user_id");


SUBSTITUIR POR ESTE

$android_tokens = array();
$x=0;
$i=0;
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

  $android_tokens[$i][] = $row["user_android_token"];
  $x++;
  // I need divide the array for 1000 push limit send in one time
  if ($x % 800 == 0) {
    $i++;
  }     
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$ip= $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$result_check = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM `notifications` WHERE notification_sender_ip = '$ip' && notification_date > DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 5 MINUTE)");
if ($result_check->num_rows > 2) {
        die('Anti flood protection. You can send only 3 notifications every 5 minutes!. This is just a demo push panel, buy this from codecanyon and install into your hosting. Thanks!');
}

$title = $_POST['title'];
$msg = $_POST['message'];
$link = $_POST['link'];

if ($android_tokens != array()) {
    $gcm=new GCM();
    $data=array("title"=>$title,"description"=>$msg,"link"=>$link);
    foreach ($android_tokens as $tokens) {
      $result_android = $gcm->send_notification($tokens,$data);
      sleep(1);
```